# what to tune tomcat for rest api

Tags: rest, tomcat

I am using Tomcat for REST API. I am trying to tune from the server side, so requests can be served asap. Some of the things I have gathered are below. Of course some params are application specific.

1) production logging - disable duplicate
2) connectiontimeout 3000
3) tcpNoDelay=”true”
4) enableLookups=”false”
5) compression=”off”
6) maxKeepAliveRequests=”1″
7) maxThreads
8) disable Automatic Servlet Reload
9) heap / perm / gc

But is there a way to disable session totally? Should I do that?
Also, caching seems not applicable. Should I disable caching totally?

Is there anything else that I can tune?